# Manipulate string from File Stream in Elixir

Tags: stream, elixir

I am new to Elixir. 
I am trying to take text from a File to turn into a graph.

The file is formatted as such:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Each number being the ID of connected nodes.

How can I take the 2 values from the String.split/1 function to somewhere else in the program ? This is what I had so far:

```
File.stream!("../text_file") 
   |> Stream.map( &(String.replace(&1, "\n", ""))) 
   |> Enum.each(String.split/1)
```

It will only output the :ok atom, but it will print the content if I swap String.split/1 for IO.puts/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.each/2` is meant to be used with functions where you don't care about the return value (usually functions with only side effects, like `IO.puts`). If you want to collect the returned data, you need `Enum.map/2`. Also, if you want to delete trailing whitespace, you should use `String.trim_trailing/1`)

```
File.stream!("a") 
|> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing/1)
|> Enum.map(&String.split/1)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[["1", "2"], ["1", "3"], ["2", "3"]]
```